# Powershell: Set-Content without evaluation

Tags: powershell

How can I set content (with the powershell console) without evaluation?

I'm in a PSSession (Remote) and want to set a script file

```
[Server1]: PS C:\Users\Admin\Documents> Set-Content -Path script.ps1 -Value @"
>>> $isStarted = $false;
>>> try
>>> {
>>>     $isStarted = (Get-NlbClusterDriverInfo).CurrentHostState -eq "Started"
>>> }
>>> catch
>>> {
>>>     Write-Host "3" # Critical
>>>     # Exit 3
>>> }
>>>
>>> if ($isStarted)
>>> {
>>>     Write-Host "0" # OK
>>>     # Exit 0
>>> }else
>>> {
>>>     Write-Host "3" # Critical
>>>     # Exit 3
>>> }
>>> "@
```

But this was written:

```
[Server1]: PS C:\Users\Admin\Documents> Get-Content .\script.ps1

True = False;
try
{
    True = (Get-NlbClusterDriverInfo).CurrentHostState -eq "Started"
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "3" # Critical
    # Exit 3
}

if (True)
{
    Write-Host "0" # OK
    # Exit 0
}else
{
    Write-Host "3" # Critical
    # Exit 3
}
```

Comment: Enclose your herestring in single quotes, i.e `@'` and `'@` instead of `@"` and `"@`.

Comment: This should be closed as it was a simple typo.